# Why is Zone Alarm Blocking VMWare Virtual Network Editor?

Tags: firewalls, vmware

I have version 15 of VMWare running on my Windows 10 computer.

When I open the Virtual Network Editor and try to add a bridged connection, I get an error saying:
`Cannot change network to bridged: There are no un-bridged host network adapters`

I know Zone Alarm is preventing this as I have to uninstall it in order to be able to add a bridged network.

Unfortunately it is not a case of disable it, but I have to uninstall it, and then I can do what I need to in the network editor.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: Did you add VMWare as an allowed program in ZoneAlarm?

Comment: Yes, VMWare is an allowed program in ZoneAlarm.

Answer (score 0):

If ZoneAlarm is preventing your application from connecting to the network you can find the Related logs and when you read the log you can find why it has been blocked and therefore you can find the right solution to solve the issue, here is [ZoneAlarm Alert and Logs](https://www.zonealarm.com/learning-center/alerts-and-logs) documentation.
ZoneAlarm has an application control mechanism that should be configured properly to allow your application from execution and data transmission and prevent the malicious program from running, here is also a helpful line to [ZoneAlarm application control](https://www.zonealarm.com/learning-center/application-control).
There should be many reason why it blocking your application from connecting to the network but a common issue is that maybe the pattern of transmitted traffic looks suspicious, like too many connections ((Behavioral Detection).